# Symfony: blank page after executing include_component()

Tags: symfony1

i have just this line in a template:

```
<?php include_component('sfGuardRegister', 'register') ?>
```

when it's executed i get a blank page. I have debugged include_component() and the flow processing is not entering inside of it, i mean:

```
function include_component($moduleName, $componentName, $vars = array())
{

  die("enter");
  echo get_component($moduleName, $componentName, $vars);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Yes, i have written a custom module+component.

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded PartialHelper?

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelper('Partial');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in production environment (index.php) blank pages will show on error. Change to development environment (frontend_dev.php) and it will tell you why there is a problem.

My bet is you haven't enabled sfGuardRegister in setting.yml:

```
all:
  enabled_modules:      [.... , sfGuardRegister]
```